# How do I leave a site

Tags: discussion

I want to know how to leave a site. I have already tried to look through every space I can. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for wanting to delete your account?  You don't have to answer if you don't want to, but from a quick look at your profile, I don't see anything apparent for doing this.

Comment: Not araqade everything else because it will not let me chat

Comment: Have you tried recently?  Your profile says you haven't logged into chat in 2.5 months.

Comment: Yes i did it said i was user someting something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you follow the instructions [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Comment: Ashley can u please delete my super user account

Comment: That info works on each site. I am just a gaming mod, not an SU one - just follow the instructions, but while on Super User.

Comment: It did not work @Ashley nunn can u ask some 1 on the bridge to delete me

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in the link I gave you. That is the only way to delete your account. No one in the Bridge can help you any better than that.